# $_GET not passing results containing value containing '#'

Tags: php, html

I am passing a value for eg : http://example.com/channel.php?channel=#football

Note : #football is an hashtag , # is used as a reference to hashtag
But on the channel.php page the value '#football' is not getting using the below code.

```
<?
if (isset($_GET['channel']) && $_GET['channel'] != "") {
    $channel = $_GET['channel'];
}
?>
```

Comment: question is, why is there a `#` passed in the first place; what's the reason for it? I think this goes deeper.

Comment: @Fred-ii- updated the question please do check

Comment: The hashtag is not meant for sending via HTTP, it's meant for resolving within the browser (i.e. HTML/JS). Omit the hashtag before sending so the value for the "channel" parameter is just "football" instead of "#football".

Answer (score 0):

The `#` symbol [ends the request part and starts the hash part](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier#Syntax) of the URI, it is not sent to the server. Use `encodeURIComponent` to encode hash and decode it back on the back-end before processing the request. So your URI should be something like this:

```
"http://example.com/channel.php?channel="+encodeURIComponent("#football")
// gives
"http://example.com/channel.php?channel=%23football"
```